# How do I read an .inf file?

Tags: c++, windows

I'd like to be able to read through the sections and values in a .inf file.

I know you can use the Profile API to read an .ini file, but am I right in understanding that an inf file is subtly different (eg, an entry may not be in an id=value format) such that the Profile API isn't suitable?

What APIs are available for reading .inf files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [SetupGetIntField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377385.aspx) and the related Setup API.